# How do I resolve a merge conflict with features?

Tags: 7, features

This might seem basic, but I am new to Drupal (and, to and extent, git).

I've made some changes to a Feature and downloaded its files to be pushed up to the remote server with git. However, I get the following merge conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  $pane->uuid = '992af322-74c5-4a5c-a261-1e73677d3645';
  $display->content['new-992af322-74c5-4a5c-a261-1e73677d3645'] = $pane;
  $display->panels['content'][2] = 'new-992af322-74c5-4a5c-a261-1e73677d3645';
=======
  $pane->uuid = 'bf806592-c85c-4155-a97c-516f72427e4e';
  $display->content['new-bf806592-c85c-4155-a97c-516f72427e4e'] = $pane;
  $display->panels['content'][2] = 'new-bf806592-c85c-4155-a97c-516f72427e4e';
  $pane = new stdClass();
>>>>>>> refs/heads/my-branch
```

I would know what to do with a conflict with other code, but this is all very foreign to me and I don't want to break anything.

Would anyone know the best course of action here?

Comment: Keep the latest changes and remove the earlier.

Comment: To the people that put it in hold. I think the context is pretty clear there...The OP is clearly asking for an advice here and he hasn't so much experience into Drupal. The question is well formulated and is related with Panes/Features, etc. Instead of just putting the question on hold, you could just help him. I know fact that this can be potentially putting off a lot of people, hence so little people in this particular stack exchange.

Comment: To be more clear, I'm not really asking a Git question - I know how to resolve most merge conflicts. The question is more about Features. As a new user `uuid = 'bf806592-c85c-4155-a97c-516f72427e4e';` means little to me and I was hoping to get some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the panes with the following uuid "bf806592-c85c-4155-a97c-516f72427e4e" 
and "992af322-74c5-4a5c-a261-1e73677d3645".
Check which one should not be there and remove it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to decide which one you will keep. If there are more that one person working on the feature then it is a good idea to wait for the other person to finish his/her modification and pull that later when he/she is done.